# Android app not always created on Fabric after changing applicationId

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have several Android applications for which I need to change the applicationId in build.gradle (or package in the APK AndroidManifest.xml).

After changing the applicationId in build.gradle, the expected behavior is Fabric seeing my application as a new one, since it has a different package name. However my apps don't show up on the Fabric dashboard most of the time, and the new version of my app and new crashes are not displayed for the old package.

So basically, **crashes and other statistics aren't recorded on the old app page, and a new app is not created even if I made it crash.**

I have also tried making a new flavor to change the applicationIdSuffix, and even changing my source code package. Both worked only once, I couldn't make both of these methods work again.

Here is a sample of the AndroidManifest.xml in my target APK, where ".fabrictest" is added to the applicationId :

```
<manifest

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:versionCode="2006001"

    android:versionName="2.6.1"

    android:installLocation="1"

    android:compileSdkVersion="28"

    android:compileSdkVersionCodename="9"

    package="com.example.myapp.fabrictest"

    platformBuildVersionCode="2006001"

    platformBuildVersionName="2.6.1"> ...
```

I plan to migrate to Firebase Crashlytics soon, but I have to keep using Fabric for now.

My questions :

- Is there a reliable way to have an app show up on Fabric, or a way to manually create one on the dashboard ?
- Is there a limit to the number of apps/flavors that can be added in a period of time ?

Answer (score 1):

Chintan from Fabric/Firebase here. There is not limit on adding apps. This probably happens because of the fact that package name is used in multiple places in an android project. Try using `Edit<find<find in path` or `Edit<find<replace in path` and rename all of those that show up there. In rare cases, your app might need manual activation, in such case reach out to [support(at)fabric(dot)io](http://mailto:support@fabric.io) with your app's package name and its Fabric Org name, and they can activate it for you.